# Como saber quais permissões uma dependência utiliza

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle

Eu tenho um App Android feito em Java publicado na loja da Getnet, na qual o sistema de aprovação deles é bastante rigoroso e recentemente tive uma versão do app reprovada por que o mesmo utiliza a permissão :
`android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGE`, porém no manifest da aplicação não consta esta permissão e nem mesmo pela tela de permissões do Android ela é visível, desconfio que seja de alguma dependência que estou utilizando.
Então a minha pergunta é :

- Como posso saber quais permissões uma dependência usa?
- Existe alguma ferramente no Android Studio ou externa que eu consiga analisar o meu Apk com mais profundidade?

Answer (score 1):

- Consegui resolver a minha questão usando o Analyse do Android Studio, ao clicar no manifest na listagem identifiquei a permissão que estava sando o problema e em seguida pesquisei no Google pra saber qual era a dependência que usa ela e acabei descobrindo que é o Firebase.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]